# Running .NET app causes error requiring .NET 4.6.2, but app targets 4.6.1

Tags: .net

I have a weird error. I have an application built against .NET 4.6.1. However, when I run it on the server, it complains that it requires .NET 4.6.2, with the following dialog:

[image]

We have other .NET 4.6.1 applications running successfully on that server.

### Server Details

Server is Windows Server 2012 R2.

The registry clearly demonstrates that .NET 4.6.1 is installed (as Release = 392471 as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed)

[image]

### Project file

Here is the ILSpy disassembly of the EXE:

```
// {HIDDEN}.exe
// {HIDDEN}, Version=1.0.17725.11651, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

// Global type: <Module>
// Entry point: {HIDDEN}.Program.Main
// Architecture: AnyCPU (64-bit preferred)
// Runtime: .NET 4.0

using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.Versioning;

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.17725.11651")]
[assembly: Debuggable(DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.IgnoreSymbolStoreSequencePoints)]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("{HIDDEN}")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("Release")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("© {HIDDEN}")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("{HIDDEN}")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.17725.11651")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.0.17725.11651")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("{HIDDEN})]
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("{HIDDEN}")]
[assembly: CompilationRelaxations(8)]
[assembly: RuntimeCompatibility(WrapNonExceptionThrows = true)]
[assembly: TargetFramework(".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1", FrameworkDisplayName = ".NET Framework 4.6.1")]
```

And from the project file

```
<TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
```

I'm out of ideas and looking for help!

Comment: Is it possible that somehow one of your *dependencies* requires 4.6.2? I would expect that to cause a build-time error, but it may depend on the exact details. I'd suggest trying to reproduce this in an isolated project - either by cutting down the existing one or starting from scratch and adding bits to it.

Comment: Maybe check all the package.config files `targetFramework` to NOT contain `net462`? Maybe this could have happened if you downgraded at some point in time?

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik We are using the new style project format so don't have a packages.config.

Comment: @JonSkeet That was my thinking too. I'm starting on the "cut-stuff-out-till-it-works" project now...

Comment: The new style project still has some info on target framework for dependencies? Somewhere in the xml, so that would be the same what @JonSkeet suggests then. As far as I know it uses nuget and nuget target is probably still the same net462, maybe do a file search for net462, v.4.6.2, etc. as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your app.config file. You may have something like this in it. Change it to 4.6.1 or remove it.

```
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" />
  </startup>
```

Comment: Although to be fair, I've just checked Source Control and it was you that added the file in the first place :P